# Count How Many Times a Number Occurs in a Cell

Tags: excel

I have a formula I am using to count the number of times a value appears in a cell, but the issue is if the cell contains a double digit number it counts it multiple times.

Ex: if I have a cell that contains `2 2 2 2 14` it sees 7 numbers - `2 2 2 2 1 4 14` when I only want it to see `2 2 2 2 14`.

I am using the formula `=((LEN(E35)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E35,"2","")))/LEN("2")*$B$2)+((LEN(E35)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E35,"3","")))/LEN("3")*$B$3)+...` (continues on for each number up to 22).

How do I make this see `14` as one number, not three?

Here's a picture to hopefully help explain. As you can see below, the "wrong val" is adding `(2800*4)+7700+41000` when it should only be adding `(2800*4)+41000`.

[image]

Error with Scott Craner's formula:

[image]

Comment: is there any text involved or only numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are only numbers then just count the spaces and add 1

```
=LEN(E35)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E35," ","")) + 1
```

[image]

---

Per your edit:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E35," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(E35)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E35," ","")) + 1))-1)*99+1,99)),$B$2:$B$18,$C$2:$C$18))
```

[image]

Comment: I should have been clearer, sorry.. I need to know the number of times each different number occurs, so I can multiply that number by another cell (hence the `*$B$2`).

Comment: I am getting `#VALUE!`. Updated photo in OP.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW not sure why as you can see it works for me.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW make sure they are spaces between the numbers and not something else.

Comment: Ah, there was a space at the end that was causing it. `2 2 2 2 14 `  vs `2 2 2 2 14`.